# Number of scanned surfaces in deep space

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

In Elite Dangerous it's possible to see various stats such as how many kills, how much you've traded, what your current inventory status is (including materials), but can you see how many scans you've collected?

I know on the Statistics section there is the ability to see how many systems and how much that has made in Credits, but I'd really like to know if there is a way to see (whilst in deep space) how many stars / planets I've scanned ready for selling.   I'd also love to know if there are stats available (that I might be missing) on how many planets I've landed on during that journey.

Does anybody know if this is something that is available?  Even if it requires working it out from the Stats menu then I guess I could live with it.